# Comparing the performance of xarray vs. NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, performance-testing

I am wondering if anyone has an example that shows the performance (memory and speed)  comparison between xarray and numpy packages. 
Thanks

Comment: I do not have a practical example yet, but in xarray, usually numpy is used as a backend. Thus, the indexing speed and memory efficiency depend on numpy. However, xarray does many sanity checks / conversion before indexing. Therefore there is a certain overhead.  For the heavy indexing that numpy needs long time, the performance does not change. For the easy indexing, the overhead of xarray might be significant.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I thought that xarray is generally faster and more efficient than numpy as xarray is designed to deal with N-dimensional arrays. I am seeking an example that gives me a comprehensive idea about that.

Comment: Well... Numpy is already designed to work with N-dimensional array. Actually, `nd` in `np.ndarray` means `N-Dimensional`. xarray is designed for N-D *labeled* arrays, where you can consider *label* as a coordinate for each dimension of arrays.

Comment: I quote the following from that [here](http://www.xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html) ...  _xarray integrates with dask to support parallel computations and streaming computation on datasets that don’t fit into memory_.

Comment: I do not have an example either. However, you can expect that (1) in most cases xarray is as fast as numpy since xarray is numpy overloaded with labeled indices, (2) looping in xarray will be slower but you can use xr.apply_ufunc to make an xarray broadcasting computation as fast [see here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#wrapping-custom-computation), (3) notwithstanding the above, selecting in xarray is slower because of validating the indices and is considered a performance issue [see here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2799)

Answer (score 2):

When comparing the performance of xarray and NumPy, it is important to note that xarray is built on top of NumPy and inherits much of its performance characteristics. In general, NumPy is likely to be faster and more efficient for simple numerical computations that involve large arrays, while xarray is better suited for more complex tasks that involve labeled arrays or multi-dimensional arrays with missing or incomplete data.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
#create two large arrays
a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
b = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

#compute the sum using NumPy
c = a + b

#create two large xarray datasets

a = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(1000, 1000), dims=['x', 'y'])
b = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(1000, 1000), dims=['x', 'y'])

#compute the sum using xarray

c = a + b
%timeit a + b  # using xarray
%timeit np.add(a, b)  # using NumPy
```

On my machine, the xarray version takes about 8.46 ms per loop, while the NumPy version takes about 1.4 ms per loop. This shows that NumPy is faster and more efficient than xarray for simple numerical operations involving large arrays.

However, it's important to note that xarray provides additional functionality beyond what NumPy provides, such as support for labeled arrays and missing data. If your task involves working with labeled or incomplete data, xarray may be the better choice despite its slightly slower performance.

```
# performance comparison using memory_profiler and timeit

import timeit
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

# define the function for the xarray approach
def xarray_approach():
    ds = xr.open_dataset('temperature.nc')
    ds_monthly = ds.resample(time='1M').mean(dim='time')
    ds_monthly.to_netcdf('monthly_mean_temperature.nc')

# define the function for the numpy approach
def numpy_approach():
    f = nc.Dataset('temperature.nc', 'r')
    t = f.variables['temperature'][:]
    t_monthly = np.mean(np.reshape(t, (-1, 30, 12)), axis=1)
    g = nc.Dataset('monthly_mean_temperature.nc', 'w')
    g.createDimension('time', None)
    g.createDimension('lat', t.shape[1])
    g.createDimension('lon', t.shape[2])
    t_var = g.createVariable('temperature', 'f4', ('time', 'lat', 'lon'))
    t_var[:] = t_monthly
    g.close()
    f.close()

# measure the memory usage and computation time of the xarray approach
xarray_memory_usage = memory_usage(xarray_approach)
xarray_time = timeit.timeit(xarray_approach, number=1)

# measure the memory usage and computation time of the numpy approach
numpy_memory_usage = memory_usage(numpy_approach)
numpy_time = timeit.timeit(numpy_approach, number=1)

# print the results
print(f"Memory usage: xarray={max(xarray_memory_usage):.2f} MB, numpy={max(numpy_memory_usage):.2f} MB")
print(f"Computation time: xarray={xarray_time:.2f} s, numpy={numpy_time:.2f} s")
```

Please make sure to install `memory_profiler` before running the code snippet above!!

Comment: The last snippet does not work.

Comment: @kernel I fixed the incomplete f-string in the last line, then installed memory_profiler.  The code runs but throws an error "file not found" because ```temperature.nc``` is missing.  
@Shashank Kumar, please provide the temperature.nc file and other files that are needed to get this code example to work.